# can we call all wrapper class as immutable?

Tags: java

can we call all wrapper class as immutable??
here Integer working like String....so have confusion in wrapper classes

```
    String s1 = "hi";
    concatString(s1);
    System.out.println(s1);
    Integer i = 10;
    changeInteger(i);
    System.out.println(i);


   private static void changeInteger(Integer i) {
      i=i+10;   
      System.out.println(i);
   }

    private static void concatString(String s1) {
        s1 = s1+"Bye";
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
```

output:hiBye
       hi
       20
       10

Comment: All wrapper classes were specifically written to be immutable... So well, YES!!

Comment: like string we are not using wrapper class usually due to performance and security issue...so what does it need

Answer (score 0):

Yes, primitive wrapper classes and `String` are immutable. I guess that the source of your confusion is the following line:

```
private static void changeInteger(Integer i) {
      i=i+10;   
      ....
```

Indeed parameter type is `Integer` and it looks like you are changing its value by adding 1. In fact before autoboxing this line looked like:

```
i = new Integer(i.intValue() + 1);
```

This line extracts `int` value from wrapper, adds `1` and then passes the result to constructor of `Integer` that creates new instance of `Integer`.

Autoboxing introduced in java 5 is a "compiler magic" feature that treats line

```
i=i+10;
```

as

```
i = new Integer(i.intValue() + 1);
```

Comment: like string we are not using wrapper class usually due to performance and security issue...so what does it need

Comment: Nit: it is `Integer.valueOf`, rather than `new Integer` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). Also - 10, rather than 1.

Comment: @AndyTurner, you are right, but `Integer.valueOf()` either gets value from cache or invokes constructor and creates new instance. These gory details however (IMHO) are not important in this case because the issue here are immutability and autoboxing.